# What is a vCard and how to read it?

Tags: contacts

What is a vCard  and how do I read it? It popped up in a message from a friend and I don't know what it is. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

A `vCard` is contact information in a standardized form, accepted by most applications that deal in people or contact information. It is transportable between systems of differing operating systems, because of its defined form, generally: Name, Address, Phone Number, Notes, etc.

In Android, the standard application to read this is called either `People` or `Contacts`. If you open the application and find the activity menu about it, one of the allowed processes will probably accept the data through "Import".

If you received it attached to a message, possibly even the messaging app will allow the import to the correct place in your system. See if its activity menu allows some processing of the attachment, similarly "Import".